# Can uBlock on FF/Win7 be configured to prevent additional pages being opened?

Tags: firefox, ublock

Can uBlock Origin be configured to prevent a new page from opening?  Not merely preventing the new page loading, I want to prevent the page it is about to block every opening a new tab (or page).

I'm using it on both Firefox and TOR on both Win7 And Linux Mint.  Besides blocking adverts, I use it to prevent unwanted ("hostile") redirects.  The intended (hostile) page might not load but still opens a new tab/page with the details of the block.  So while the new page is 'benign.' it still leaves me having to close a useless page.  It would be more beneficial to me if iBlock stopped the redirect without opening a new tab/page, or for that matter, giving me any indication that anything has happened.

Is this configurable?